# How to return value from new object instance method declaration (nested)?

Tags: java, android

Ok this is the code:

public boolean alertDialog(String message){

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TestBedAppActivity.this.agree = true;
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            TestBedAppActivity.this.agree = false;
            dialog.cancel();
        }

    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Inside the setPositiveButton() methos there is a nested declaration of the method onClick(). I want to return the boolean result for the main method alertDialog(String message) but I cannot do it. What am I missing? Help!!!!!!!

Comment: you want to do what? describe "cannot do it"

Comment: I want to return the boolean value for the main method (outer one) from inside the onClick() methods.

Answer (score 1):

onClick runs when the user click the positive button or the cancel button. When you call "alert.show()", this method returns at once. So you  don't know return what since the user operation does not happen.

Comment: You can separate your code to the showing dialog codes and the response codes from user actions.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know any solution. Your code runs at the UI thread and you must not hang up the code to wait for the user action.